# How to move a Debian pxe server on a new lan (VLAN)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vlan

I set up a Debian pxe server on a lan. Everything works fine. In case a VLAN is created and I want to put pxe server on the new lan, what should I do?

I mean if the Debian pxe ip is currently 192.168.0.10, if I want to move it on a VLAN (VLAN 1) do I only need to change its static ip and update the default gateway accordingly? In a nutshell: ip 192.168.197.3 and default gw 192.168.197.254, is that correct?

I do believe it's wrong...can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IP subnet VLAN1 is on is indeed 192.168.197.0/24 then yes I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work - and of course that no other devices are using the static IP you're attempting to use for your PXE server.

If you're asking how would you make the PXE server available to more than just one subnet you can do that via the IP helper (e.g., "ip helper-address 192.168.197.254" in a Cisco router or L3-capable switch) for your DHCP server - other switch vendors have similar types of options to permit DHCP relaying across subnets.  The DHCP can in turn then be configured to hand out DHCP options 66 and 67 for your PXE boot process.  An example of this for ISC DHCP:

```
subnet 192.168.197.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.197.100 192.168.197.254;
        default-lease-time 3600;
        max-lease-time 4800;
        option routers 192.168.197.254;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.197.254;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.197.254;
        **filename "pxelinux.0";
        next-server 192.168.197.3;**
}
```

Obviously the method varies for Microsoft DHCP, Infoblox, VitalQIP, etc. but the options (66 and 67, TFTP hostname and bootstrap filename, respectively) are the same no matter how the DHCP server is configured or what vendor you're using.

And, since you seem to be assuming you'll be supporting multiple subnets/VLAN with this one DHCP server obviously you'd want to define subnet ranges and DHCP IP address pools for all VLANs you add.